# Поиск по параметру

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, помогите, пожалуйста, уже всю голову сломал почему не срабатывает.
Вообщем вот код

```
if ($search) {
if($group_s == "" || $number_s == "" || $famely_s == "") {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM file WHERE id = '$id_s'");
} elseif($id_s == "" || $number_s == "" || $famely_s == "") {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM file WHERE group = '$group_s'");
} elseif ($id_s == "" AND $group_s == "" AND $number_s == "") {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM file WHERE famely = '$famely_s'");
}
}  else {
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM file ")  or die ( mysql_error() );
}
```

Есть 4 параметра: айди, группа, фамилия, номер. Поиск по айди идет, а по другим не работает. С чем может быть связанно?

Comment: с тем что условия неверные

Comment: По айди ищет, а по этим двумя фемели и групп не ищет, как исправить то ?

Comment: для начала надо определиться по какому условию должно искаться? Если указан id тогда искать по id? Что искать если указана группа и фамилия?

Comment: http://hashcode.ru/questions/318718/php-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8

Comment: Не помогло взял в `id` `groups_s`

Comment: Есть какой-то пример чтобы работало, как по отдельным полям, так и по нескольким.

Comment: Попробуй в условиях использовать "&&", вместо "||", а вообще, какие то странные условия...
Нужно искать по какому то одному полю или по любому заполненному полю?

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($group_s) // Если строка $group_s не пустая
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM file WHERE group = '$group_s'");
elseif ($famely_s) // Если строка $famely_s не пустая
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM file WHERE famely = '$famely_s'");
elseif ($id_s) // Если строка $id_s не пустая
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM file WHERE id = '$id_s'");
else // Если никакое из условий не было выполнено.
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM file ")  or die ( mysql_error() );
```

Вариант 2:

```
$condition = array(); // Подготавливаем массив для условий

if ($group_s) // Если не пустая то добовляем условие на группу
    $conditions[] = "group = '$group_s'";

if ($famely_s) // Если не пустая то добовляем условие на семейство
    $conditions[] = "famely = '$famely_s'";

if ($id_s) // Если не пустая то добовляем условие на ID
    $conditions[] = "id = '$id_s'";

$count = count($conditions); // Получаем кол-во условий(элементов в массиве $conditions)

$query = "SELECT * FROM file "; // Базовая часть запроса

if ($count > 0) // Если есть условия(кол-во условий больше 0)
{
    $query .= "WHERE "; // Добовляем к строке запроса WHERE
    foreach($conditions as $key => $condition) // Перебираем массив условий $key - ключ массив
    {
        $query .= $condition; // Добовляем к строке условие
        if ($key != ($count - 1) && $count > 1) // Смотрим если ключ массива неравен последнему элементу(есть еще условия) и условий больше одного
            $query .= " AND "; // то добовляем к строке AND
    }
}

$result = mysql_query($query)  or die ( mysql_error() ); // Делаем запрос
```

Comment: count - 1, потому что функция $count возвращает кол-во элементов. А отчет элементов в массиве начинается с 0.

Comment: Можно немного упростить код, убрав цикл и воспользоваться функцией преобразования массива в строку: join.
    $where = join(" AND ", $conditions);